# Different response time for post on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a web service to which data is posted. What I do is parse the json and store the data.

And my response is

```
render json: { success: true, message: "ok" }, status: 200
```

Active record takes about 10ms to complete the inserts. There are no views so rails returns something like 0.4 ms to render them. What I find strange are the response time, that are always different (ok, 20 ms up or down is ok, but those are the response times): 130ms, 62ms, 149ms, 71ms, 77ms, 150ms, 48ms, 72ms

My app is on Heroku (I only have new relic enabled, no other request). Does anyone know why the difference or a good way to test it? Maybe because of new Relic?

Comment: Could be the environment the web server is running on, the dbms and it's environment,  the connection between them.. Very hard to nail down. Loads of logging to the console, until you get a clue as to where the problem might be. Contentions in the rails code or the database would be the first thing I would look for.

Comment: Might also be that garbage collection kicks in every now and then. You could try a GC.start before a request is handled and to disable GC during requests.

Comment: GC, and also isn't heroku a shared environment? Load on the box for other people will affect your instance.